Reusing a codebook/technique in a new publication
I have published a paper, hereby referred as "the first paper", where I lay out a conceptual framework that categorises and evaluates, let's say, policies. This article got published with a detailed codebook, including the categories, unit of analysis, examples, etc.
Now I have written another article. I inspect a similar set of policies, but from different actors. However, I simply re-used the categories and techniques I used in the first paper. I cite the first paper, of course, in the methodology part of the new paper. When I presented this paper in a conference, someone said that I should put all the information about coding/categories in the appendix.
Well, this codebook already exists in the first one's appendix. Now that I am getting ready to send the new paper for publication I am trying to understand what to do...
Do I simply put a footnote/endnote saying the details of coding exists in the appendix of the first article? Do I rewrite the whole codebook for the second one and cite the first article in the appendix again? How to navigate re-using same categorisation/codebook/research design (developed by myself) in two different articles?

Do you hold copyright to the first paper?

It is not open access and behind a paywall, so I'd say no.

Ask the editor of the second journal.

As an analogy, psychologists routinely use the same questionnaire over and over again. (As just one example, take Beck's Depression Inventory.) These are well established in the literature, and nobody would put the BDI into a new publication. If you really need it, you know where and how to get it.
In this specific case, of course the BDI is copyrighted. So as Buffy notes, there is the added question of whether you even have the right to re-publish material, or whether you signed that right away with the first paper.
Bottom line: I personally would submit the second paper without the codebook, but of course with a prominent pointer as to where it was first published. Then see what the reviewer and the editors say. If they truly want it in an appendix, you can start worrying about copyright. (I don't think anyone would make this a reason to reject the paper.) And conversely, as a reviewer or AE, I would never recommend reprinting material like this - to the contrary, if someone included material for republication, I would expect a convincing explanation for why they would do that, because it raises the question of whether anything was changed between the first and the second publication.

I mean, the first paper (with the codebook) is already published in a peer-reviewed journal. The second one is in the works. I was thinking of adding a footnote saying, "For details of the coding process and codebook, please see the appendix in Rhyso (2023)". Wouldn't that be sufficient?

Yes, that is precisely what I am recommending.

@Buffy: thank you for pointing that out. Edited.

My problem is that... well then the anonymity is out of the window? Isn't this a problem?

Well, you can always write "we used the codebook introduced by rhyso (2024)". The reviewers will strongly suspect you are the same author, or at least that there is a nonempty intersection between the two papers' author lists. But you could have reused someone else's prior work, that happens all the time. And there really is no way around it. Simply reprinting the codebook without attributing the earlier paper is absolutely not an option.

Both solo authored articles :)

There are two considerations, copyright and self plagiarism. You need to respect the first and avoid the second.
The question of "usage" of the technique in research is different. Yes, you can reuse the technique as it is, essentially, an idea. And ideas, even copyrighted ones are free to use. Patents are a different matter, however, but you don't suggest that is an issue.
There is also the question, related to usage, as to whether the second paper will be treated by a publisher as "sufficiently novel" to warrant publication. But that is up to them to decide.
The rest of this focuses on how you write the second paper.
My recommendation is that you don't duplicate the appendix without permission of the copyright holder, but that you the original paper and point to its appendix. Following that, you can use excerpts (suitably labelled) from it to help explain things in the second paper, or paraphrase what is there, again with citation. This is standard copyright practice.
Don't try to rewrite that appendix with different words but the same intellectual content in the new paper. Especially without citing the original. That would be self plagiarism. A reader wants and needs full context of ideas and if they were originally expressed in the first paper, then you need to cite that.
You could, of course, ask the copyright holder for permission to duplicate the appendix, citing it as "with permission". This avoids all problems.
One issue with copyright is that when a new publication infringes in such a way as to reduce the value (usually economic value) of the original, copyright holders are likely to object. Reproducing it without permission in your case seems like it would have precisely that effect.

I am thinking of submitting without any mention of the codebook and adding it (the reference) in the latter rounds of review/editing.

Depending on what else you say, you might be flirting with self plagiarism. Citation is likely a better choice.

Well I use the same sources to explain where the categorisation comes from, but these are somewhat commonly used works for my field. So I paraphrase it and I even provide a "this method is used different applications" sentence and cite my own work. Just not the codebook, directly.

Just a note that paraphrasing isn't a defense.

If I use the same design I have in another article, I still have to explain the design and where it comes from - that's the paraphrasing part, and I refer to my own article as well? There are plenty other article that use very similar methods. I can't see the part where this goes into the self-plagiarism route?

Just a clarification, I am referring to research design section-not to a codebook/appendix
